# Is the covariance of standardized variables the correlation?

Tags: correlation, covariance, standardization

I have a basic question.  Say I have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$.  I can standardize them by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation, i.e., $X_{standardized} = \frac{(X - E(X))}{(SD(X))}$.

Is the correlation of $X$ and $Y$, $Cor(X, Y)$, the same as the covariance of the standardized versions of $X$ and $Y$?  That is, is $Cor(X, Y) = Cov(X_{standardized}, Y_{standardized})$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{corr}(X,Y)&=\frac{E\Big((X-E(X))\times(Y-E(Y))\Big)}{SD(X)\times SD(Y)}\\
\operatorname{Cov}(X_{\text{standardized}}, Y_{\text{standardized}})
&=E\Bigg[\Bigg(\frac{(X - E(X))}{(SD(X))}-0\Bigg)\times\Bigg(\frac{(Y - E(Y))}{(SD(Y))}-0\Bigg)\Bigg]\\
&= \frac{E\Big((X-E(X))\times(Y-E(Y))\Big)}{SD(X)\times SD(Y)}
\end{align}$$So, Yes!

Comment: What???? The right side of your first equation is a random variable while the left side is a constant.

Comment: @DilipSarwate is it fine now :)

Comment: Errr no. The question is about correlation and covariance of _random variables_ whereas your answer is about _sample_ correlation and covariance. For example, the result asked about holds for continuous random variables whereas at best what you have applies only to discrete random variables taking on values $(X_1,Y_1), \ldots, (X_n,Y_n)$ with equal probability $\frac 1n$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Now!?

Comment: Not quite. You don't need the subscripts $i$ at all, so I have gone ahead and deleted them, and improved the presentation a little bit. Feel free to roll back if you don't like the changes.

Comment: You are taking SD(X) and SD(Y) out of expectation. Explain the reasoning of this step a little bit more please.

Comment: @Erdogan constants can be taken outside of Expected() function without change.